# Any complete fix Mixed Content WP Plugin?

Tags: wordpress, ssl

Why all fix Mixed Content WP Plugin claim that it will slow down the website performance? Any plugin can auto covert all http to https at first time then we can uninstall the plugin, so it wont slow down the website performance.

Comment: There is no complete auto fix solution [ at least for free ], you have to use some plugins like SSL Insecure Content Fixer and then also check any remaining issues by checking on every page and solving them manually.

Comment: why SSL Insecure Content Fixer affect the website performance? can i activate it to convert all http to https then delete the plugin? After i delete the plugin, the https will be back to http right? LOLS.

Comment: Sorry I haven't seen it yet **SSL Insecure Content Fixer affect the website performance** mostly on all of my websites, I use this plugin and never seen its resources throttling site speed

Comment: this is what i copy from ssl insecure content fixer official page description "The Capture fix level captures the entire page, and fixes scripts, stylesheets, images, iframes, and embeds (videos, tunes) anywhere on the page. NB: it can chew up lots of memory on big pages, which can impact website performance. Choose it if you need it, but see if you can use a lower impact level first."

Comment: thanks :) I will do research on same

Comment: some link dont have http, and dont have www. No idea how to replace them with https.

Answer (score 0):

I recommand using [Search Replace DB](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)

Use it once to find **http** and convert them to **https** and delete it after.

If you need to make remplacements in the files, I would recommand using Sublime Text and its Search and Replace feature.

Comment: yes. Found the solution for db, any plugin as solution for every file in directory folder?

Comment: if db record save link like haha.com without www and without http, how to replace them with https?